# Minimize a maximized Chromium browser - by using a button

Tags: javascript, html, chromium

I am using Chromium to launch a particular url, via a desktop shortcut (there are business reasons for using Chromium).

As it stands, I am using fullscreen set to true, to make sure the app/browser opens at the full height and width of the device where it runs.

However, now I need a way for a user to minimize the app. There is the <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> key - which is great, but I would like to put this functionality behind a button;

How can I send the <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to the OS, from behind a browser button click?

Comment: You can’t from unprivileged JavaScript. That would be a horrible security problem.

Comment: Alternatively, could one add a toolbar with sizing options to the Chromium app itself?